# Point set topology from an algebraic perspective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, reference-request

I got this idea of viewing a topology as an operation on a ring of sets.

Let $\mathcal R = (\mathcal P(X), \cap, \triangle)$ be a ring of sets. ($\triangle$ is the symmetric difference operation and $\cap$ is the usual set intersection).

A topology on the ring $\mathcal R$ can be viewed as an [operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms) (the link is thanks to a comment by Marek) $-: \mathcal R\to \mathcal R$ that sends every element to it's (topological) closure. $($That is $-: A \mapsto \overline{A})$.

In order for the operation to be a topology it must satisfy the following conditions:

$$\forall i \in I \space(\overline{A_i} = A_i) \implies \overline{\bigcap A_i} = \bigcap{A_i}$$

$$\forall i \in I  \space (\overline{A_i} = A_i) \land (I \text{ is finite}) \implies \overline{A_1  \triangle A_2 \triangle A_3 \cdots \triangle \bigcap A_i} = \overline{A_1}   \triangle \overline{A_2} \triangle \overline{A_3} \cdots \triangle \overline{\bigcap A_i} $$

$$ (\overline X = X) \land (\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset).$$

$(\mathcal R,-)$ is a represntation of a topological space and the opration $-$ contains all the information about the topology.

Is this a known construction?  Is it worthwhile to think about this at all?

I'l be happy to be pointed to a reference that discusses this.

I wonder whether in this framework some results about point set topology could be obtained from pure ring theoretic consideration and thus some proofs could be extensively simplified.

Comment: In the early days of general topology (roughly, 1920s through 1940s), quite a bit of work was done on these kinds of ideas. The following date-restricted google-books search for the phrase ["topological functions"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22topological+functions%22&"tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1920%2Ccd_max%3A1950&tbm=bks) will give you some places to begin looking.

Comment: Strange . . . When I created the URL and checked that it worked, it produced results from 1920 to 1950. However, after I posted my comment and clicked on the embedded URL, the date-restricted aspect of the search was no longer present. You'll need to put in the date restriction I suggested (1920 to 1950), or you'll be snowed under by a bunch of stuff of little relevance for your question.

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms

Comment: "Is this a known construction? " Yes. "Is it worthwhile to think about this at all?" Yes, but not too long.  "I wonder whether [...] results [...]  could be extensively simplified." Yes.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks! Could you give an example illustrating your third "yes"?

Comment: Pontryagin's book "Topological Groups" defines a topology in terms of the closure operation. It might be worth checking out if you're interested in how it would be done.